# Remove lines with a pattern ABC which do not contain a pattern MNO from a file

Tags: shell, text-manipulation

```
$ cat File1
MNO ABC
MNO ABC
ABC
vzcbjzcb
```

After removing the lines, it should look like this:

```
MNO ABC 
MNO ABC
zcvshskl
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with **Perl** as follows:

```
perl -nle 's/ABC//g if !m/MNO/; print if length($_)' File1
```

That says... *"Process all lines of `File1` handling line endings automatically (`-nle`). Replace (substitute) `ABC` with nothing if the line doesn't match `MNO`. Print the line if it is not empty."*

Note that this will not retain empty lines in your input file but I trust that is not a problem.

You can do much the same with **awk**:

```
awk '!/MNO/{gsub(/ABC/,"")} length($0)' File1
```

Or with **sed**:

```
sed -e '/MNO/!s/ABC//g' -e '/^\s*$/d' File1
```

If you really, really want to do it in **bash**:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
   [[ ! $line =~ MNO ]] && line=${line/ABC/}
   [ ${#line} -gt 0 ] && echo $line
done < File1
```

Comment: Is it Possible With Shell , I am Not using Pearl I am Using Bash....(Shell Script)

Comment: You can, but why would you? It is awkward and slow - the point of Unix is to have small programs that do specific things well and then chain them together to achieve harder things. `awk`, `sed` and `Perl` are all good at this sort of thing.

Comment: i have this command sed '/MNO/s/ABC//' File1 But , This Will Remove The Pattern ABC Which Contain pattern MNO in The Same Line, Is it Possible To Negate This Command ....Answer Pls.

Comment: That is exactly what my **sed** version shows. The exclamation mark inverts it.

Comment: hi, One More Query.....Same Thing, If we have pattern which Is include 'ABC' instead of ABC .....Now How can I escape The single quote  . And 'ABC' pattern Is not the end of the Line , That pattern May be Present In the Between the line Also.....Pls solve the Query...

Comment: Put a backslash before each single quote `/\'ABC\'/`

Comment: awk '!/MNO/{gsub(/\'ABC\'/,"")} length($0)'...Its Not Working in My file1  is line this : 
  line   1  agbabsjb 'ABC' jncsaknsclk
  line   2  MNO 'ABC' nkjj
  line   3  MNO 'ABC' Ihiojhsc
  line   4  'ABC'
  line   5  nknkncksn  please Remove only Pattern 'ABC'..........Line 1 And 4